# How to set the alignment of the chart in matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python

I have two numpy.ndarray and both have the same number of datas as follow :

```
data1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data2 = [Nan, Nan, Nan, 14,15,16,17,18,19]
```

When, I plot these data, the data1 occupies the whole width of the window. But since data2 has NaN, only the non-NaN data will be shown on the window and they are in the middle.

How can I set the matplotlib.pyplot so that they are aligned on the right side/edge of the window?

---

[image]

Hi, the screenshot1 is the actual situation. The screenshot 2 is what I want, i.e. the charts are right aligned.

Comment: please show us your undesired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your uploaded figures, what you want to do is to set the x-axis' range e.g.:

```
plt.xlim((np.min(data2), np.max(data2)))
```

See here: https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim

Otherwise please try to explain more accurately, what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Adding x values (using x-y pairs) could help you probably to align the data as you want.

```
plt.plot(x, data)
plt.plot(x, data2)
plt.show()
```

Where x is an array e.g. [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: This is not a good idea since you have to add another new array.

Comment: And why would be that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not plotting the data array, but a masked array in case of NaN's could help.

```
import numpy as np

data2_masked = np.ma.masked_array(data2, mask=np.isnan(data2)
```

And then plot the masked array instead of the `data2` array containing the `nan` values

Comment: This doesn't help. It is the same as before.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the plot of `data2` having an x axis from the min value to the max value of `data2`?